# Odd DFA for Language

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, automata, computation-theory

Can somebody please help me draw a NFA that accepts this language:

`{ w | the length of w is 6k + 1 for some k ≥ 0 }`

I have been stuck on this problem for several hours now. I do not understand where the `k` comes into play and how it is used in the diagram...

Comment: Off-topic here, belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

`{ w | the length of w is 6k + 1 for some k ≥ 0 }`

We can use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to constructively produce a provably minimal DFA for this language. This is a useful exercise. First, a definition:

> Two strings `w` and `x` are *indistinguishable* with respect to a language `L` iff: (1) for every string `y` such that `wy` is in `L`, `xy` is in `L`; (2) for every string `z` such that `xz` is in `L`, `wz` is in `L`.

The insight in Myhill-Nerode is that if two strings are indistinguishable w.r.t. a regular language, then a minimal DFA for that language will see to it that the machine ends up in the same state for either string. Indistinguishability is reflexive, symmetric and transitive so we can define equivalence classes on it. Those equivalence classes correspond directly to the set of states in the minimal DFA. Now, to find the equivalence classes for our language. We consider strings of increasing length and see for each one whether it's indistinguishable from any of the strings before it:

1. `e`, the empty string, has no strings before it. We need a state `q0` to correspond to the equivalence class this string belongs to. The set of strings that can come after `e` to reach a string in `L` is `L` itself; also written `c(c^6)*`
2. `c`, any string of length one, has only `e` before it. These are not, however, indistinguishable; we can add `e` to `c` to get `ce = c`, a string in `L`, but we cannot add `e` to `e` to get a string in `L`, since `e` is not in `L`. We therefore need a new state `q1` for the equivalence class to which `c` belongs. The set of strings that can come after `c` to reach a string in `L` is `(c^6)*`.
3. It turns out we need a new state `q2` here; the set of strings that take `cc` to a string in `L` is `ccccc(c^6)*`. Show this.
4. It turns out we need a new state `q3` here; the set of strings that take `ccc` to a string in `L` is `cccc(c^6)*`. Show this.
5. It turns out we need a new state `q4` here; the set of strings that take `cccc` to a string in `L` is `ccc(c^6)*`. Show this.
6. It turns out we need a new state `q5` here; the set of strings that take `ccccc` to a string in `L` is `cc(c^6)*`. Show this.
7. Consider the string `cccccc`. What strings take us to a string in `L`? Well, `c` does. So does `c` followed by any string of length 6. Interestingly, this is the same as `L` itself. And we already have an equivalence class for that: `e` could also be followed by any string in `L` to get a string in `L`. `cccccc` and `e` are indistinguishable. What's more: since all strings of length 6 are indistinguishable from shorter strings, we no longer need to keep checking longer strings. Our DFA is guaranteed to have one the states `q0` - `q5` we have already identified. What's more, the work we've done above defines the transitions we need in our DFA, the initial state and the accepting states as well:

   - The DFA will have a transition on symbol `c` from state `q` to state `q'` if `x` is a string in the equivalence class corresponding to `q` and `xc` is a string in the equivalence class corresponding to `q'`;
   - The initial state will be the state corresponding to the equivalence class to which `e`, the empty string, belongs;
   - A state `q` is accepting if any string (hence all strings) belonging to the equivalence class corresponding to the language is in the language; alternatively, if the set of strings that take strings in the equivalence class to a string in `L` includes `e`, the empty string.

We may use the notes above to write the DFA in tabular form:

```
q    x    q'
--   --   --
q0   c    q1 //     e + c = c
q1   c    q2 //     c + c = cc
q2   c    q3 //    cc + c = ccc
q3   c    q4 //   ccc + c = cccc
q4   c    q5 //  cccc + c = ccccc
q5   c    q0 // ccccc + c = cccccc ~ e
```

We have `q0` as the initial state and the only accepting state is `q1`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a NFA which goes 6 states forward then if there is one more character it stops on the final state. Otherwise it loops back non-deterministcally to the start and past the final state.

```
(Start) S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S5 -> S6 -> S7 (Final State) -> S8 - (loop forever)
                                                           ^ |
        ^                        v                         |_|
        |________________________| (non deterministically)
```

Comment: Could you draw a picture I am having a hard time visualizing this. You are saying it loops back to S1 and then skips S7 later? Does it ever get to S8?

Comment: It doesn't skip S7. After S6 it nondeterministically goes to S7 and S1. Then the branch that goes to S7 will either stop if it is on its 6kth+1 input or it will go to S8 and stay in that loop until the input runs out. The other nondeterministic branch is back at S1 and repeats the pattern with the remaining input.

Comment: Off topic. Too complicated: in my book, every DFA is an NFA.

Comment: @greybeard I am not sure what you mean by that. Of course a DFA can be written as a NFA and vice versa, but what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: **Not** _can be written as_, but _is_ (the same way an O(n) algorithm is O(n³) or a regular language is context-free). Care to refer to definitions of DFA and NFA? (BTW, your loop is short.)

Comment: DFAs are NFAs maybe, but NFAs do not work as DFAs necessarily. Could you explain what the actual problem is with my answer, what do you mean by the loop is short?